# R - Panel Plot With Multiple Lines Per Panel

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I need to create a panel line plot where each panel has multiple lines within in and each panel uses the same x and same y axes. My data set looks like:

Alaska  4   20  A
Alaska  6   40  A
Alaska  8   80  A
Alaska  12  100 A
Vermont 4   10  A
Vermont 6   30  A
Vermont 8   50  A
Vermont 12  60  A
Utah    4   10  A
Utah    6   20  A
Utah    8   25  A
Utah    12  45  A
Alaska  4   10  B
Alaska  6   20  B
Alaska  8   50  B
Alaska  12  80  B
Vermont 4   30  B
Vermont 6   50  B
Vermont 8   60  B
Vermont 12  70  B
Utah    4   25  B
Utah    6   45  B
Utah    8   55  B
Utah    12  65  B
Alaska  4   15  C
Alaska  6   30  C
Alaska  8   60  C
Alaska  12  70  C
Vermont 4   15  C
Vermont 6   25  C
Vermont 8   45  C
Vermont 12  80  C
Utah    4   20  C
Utah    6   35  C
Utah    8   40  C
Utah    12  55  C

The code to read the data is:

```
library(ggplot2);
data = read.table("test_set.dat");
names(data) <- c("Place", "Variable", "Value", "Condition");
data$Place <- as.factor(data$Place);
data$Variable <- as.factor(data$Variable);
data$Value <- as.numeric(data$Value);
data$Condition <- as.factor(data$Condition);
```

So I need a panel for each Place. X axis is Variable. Y axis is Value. Each line should be Condition, and there should be a legend with a title of "Condition".

Can I do this in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first transformed the data to long format using the melt function of the reshape package. I then plotted the data as you described, grouping by Condition and separating the Places into Facets.

```
library(reshape)
data_gather <- melt(data)

ggplot(data=data_gather, aes(x=Variable, y=value, group=Condition, color=Condition)) 
 + geom_line() 
 + facet_wrap(~ Place, ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed :-D

Comment: But question: How can I use theme to change the legend and axis titles? It seems when I use theme to change the axis, it makes the legend disappear.

Comment: Look at this very good description on legends: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/